# Search & jump between lines in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am new and I hate files with more than 1000 lines of code because I have to scroll alot.

So my question is when I am working on a line and I have to look up to a name of some property, how do I find that property name fast and how do I jump back to the line I was actually editing without scrolling alot?

What options do I have?

Comment: Just ask a question. Don't express your feelings :)

Comment: Use bookmarks : http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Comment: Ctrl + M + O collapses all your methods and gives you a nice overview of your code. It's pretty sweet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains all `methods`, `fields`, `properties`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio, the following short-cuts exist (by default).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> - Allows you to search for a method or class name.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> - Allows you to 'jump' to a line number, if you can remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Iam currently working in big files. And i tend to use ctrl + kk  alot. Which is bookmark. u can use Ctrl k + P and Ctrl k + b to get to previous and next bookmark. I also use find find all refrences alot. Right click some code and press find all refrences.

Hope it helps! =)

Comment: That is a nice idea :))

Comment: yeah you will love it, make sure that u remove the ones you are done with. Too many bookmarks is superconfusing :P

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code editor, there will be a combobox which displays all the members of current class(which is located in top right corner of editor). Select the property you are interested. It will navigate you to the property definition.

To get back to the place where you were  Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (Navigate backward command).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl + F for searching the specific property and use Navigate Backward: Shift+Alt+3; Navigate Forward: Shift+Alt+4 to get back to the editing line.

Hope this may help you.